# Running out of memory errors with pillow and python 2.7.10

Tags: python, image, out-of-memory, python-imaging-library

I am experiencing seemingly random errors in a 32bit python 2,7,10 using the latest pillow release 2.8.2 on win7

My setup is the following: I have a main window that shows an image in a canvas loaded via

```
img=Image.open(...)

self.img=ImageTk.PhotoImage.(img)
```

However, I also have an overview window that displays a scaled down version of the same image, basically using the same approach starting with the current filename. As long as the images aren't well beyond 10k x 5k pixels, I do not seem to encounter problems. However, once I get beyond that limit, I get IOStream Errors and out of memory errors.
Using the 64bit version has, as expected, not yet produced the same errors (as more memory can be used by python).

If you are interested in seeing the actual piece of software, its freely available at:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/itagbiology/

No, this is not a post to generate downloads.
You will see that the small size image loads very slowly. If you load up huge images larger than 10k x 5k (depending on your pc), it will sometimes crash.

I'm sort of lost here, since I cannot think of anything to catch errors, since an out of memory error can occur at any time! I have caught the ioerror by replacing the preview image with a blank image, however, the main image must be guaranteed to load.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I guess you are either "running into an error" or experience a "'running out of memory' error ... Can you please update the title ?

Comment: Well, its both... It is actually pretty weird... I get the IOerror only within the preview window where I load the fille and resize it. If I go to the next image at feasible res (say 4k by 5k) AND THEN go back, I get an out of memory error from the function that loads the main canvas image. I assume this is both related to memory issues, since I do not experience any problems when using 64bit.

Comment: If the crashes are unhandled exceptions, capture the tracebacks and post them here. These tracebacks tell you *where* and *how* things went wrong.

Comment: @SachaViquerat what I was talking about is that you wrote you are running out of error. Like a car that is running out of fuel. And I think your problem is not that you no longer have enough errors to continue ;-)

Comment: oops... I tend to get blind after hours of coding... :)

Comment: On a related topic: Is it normal that displaying a 10k x 10k image and loading up a 500x500 version takes up about 1.5 to 2 gig of memory? It seems huge for a jpg file at 30 to 40 mb. I also get decompression bomb warnings. Is there any way to improve image loading except for chunking it up?